# Spring 2.3.4 Creation of a bean in function

Tags: java, spring, soap

I'm working on Spring 2.3.4 and I need to create a bean (wsS4jSecurityInterceptor) for webServices calls (SOAP). The userName and password are sent by a method

```
Public class Foo {
 public Foo(){};
 public boolean initialization(String userName, String password) {//creation of the bean wsS4jSecurityInterceptor}
 public void fooCallWS(FooType fooVar){//call WS}
}
```

Usually I create the bean of the wsS4jSecurityInterceptor in the configuration file but this time I have to do it in a function of my Foo class. I can't find any information to do it with Spring 2.3.4 (the solutions I found work on version 3 or 5). Do you have a solution to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What are the solutions you found for version 3 or 5?  Is it about the creation and injection of beans from a function, or your question is actually about how to create a wS4SecurityInterceptor bean type??

Comment: I suspect you're using Spring Boot 2.3.4, which is quite new, and not Spring 2.x, which is very, very, very old.

Comment: My question is how to create a bean wss4JSecurityInterceptor in the "initialization" function so that I can add security in the header at the time of the WS call. I forgot a little detail is that my method must return a boolean if everything went well (I have other actions to perform and check in this method). I made the modification on the post. 

Yes it's Spring Boot 2.3.4 I forgot "boot" due to language abuse